# check particular letter entered is capitalize in capybara

Tags: cucumber, capybara

How to check that particular 1 character entered in the text area is capitalize in capybara.

Example:- In text area i have entered
architect is an an publication.

so how can we check and put validation that "architect" should be in capital letter in capybara /cucumber

Answer (score 2):

You can get the text the textarea by doing the following:

```
textarea_text = page.find(:css, 'textarea').text
```

Note that if there is more than one textarea on the page, you will need to make the locator more specific.

From the text of the textarea, you can get the first letter by doing:

```
textarea_text[0]
 #=> "a"
```

You can capitalize a string by doing:

```
textarea_text[0].capitalize
#=> "A"
```

Therefore your step could be something like:

```
Then /the first letter should be capitalized/ do
  textarea_text = page.find(:css, 'textarea').text
  first_letter = textarea_text[0]
  first_letter.should == first_letter.capitalize
end
```